# Java, how to make a thread that watches the state of a program?

Tags: java, multithreading, state

I want to create a thread that will be constantly running in the background checking the state of a program as it runs. I just want to know how to keep it running and how to make the thread.

Comment: I think your question has been sufficiently answered. In order to accept an answer, click the 'check-mark' next to the answer that you think best answers your question.

Answer (score 6):

```
Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(new ApplicationMonitor());

class ApplicationMonitor implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        // do your monitoring stuff
    }
}
```

ApplicationMonitor should never return and never allow exceptions to be thrown. Alternately, and maybe more safely, make the ApplicationMonitor do just one check, and put the submit() call in a loop. Then the monitoring can fail, and it will be restarted later:

```
while (true) {
    try {
        Future<?> future = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(
                    new ApplicationMonitor());
        future.get(); // can add a timeout here to limit the monitoring thread
    } catch (Exception e) {
        reportMonitoringException(e);
    }
    sleepUntilNextMonitoringCycle();
}
```

Finally, you can have Java do the scheduling for you:

```
ScheduledExecutorService executorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
executorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
    new ApplicationMonitor(), 0, 30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

With this approach, you can't get a Future for all the scheduled invocations, so your exceptions would have to be handled within the ApplicationMonitor.

Answer (score 2):

You know there is a [`Thread`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) class, right?

```
Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted()){
            // do stuff
        }
    }
});
t.start();
```

For future reference, I'd recommend reading [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://jcip.net/) if you're going to continue developing multi-threaded applications.

**EDIT -** Also, if you require more sophistication, I recommend reading up on the [`Executors`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) framework.

Comment: how do i keep the thread running so it doesn't stop? just constantly checks whatever i tell it to check?

Comment: @Joe F, See my edit. The thread will continue to execute unless it's issued an `interrupt()`, which may need to be propagated, given certain circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a [Runnable](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runnable.html) that checks the state of your program (how the state of your program is checked is of course up to you to figure out), then give it to a [Thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html) and start the thread.

There are a couple of examples in the javadocs I've linked that provide a basis for your code. For more details and more advanced concurrency facilities, check out the [Java Concurrency learning trail](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/).

Comment: They are in my answer - 'Runnable', 'Thread' and 'Java Concurrency learning trail'

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do two main things:

1. Start your monitoring thread (see @Moonbeam's answer)
2. Make the target program suitable for monitoring

To achieve the second item is a lot more complex than you might think. Things to consider are:

- making any fields you are watching `volatile`
- using synchronized access to groups of fields that together comprise a consistent state, so that updates are "atomic"